# Getting Crash in cellForRowAtIndexPath in tableView on Crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, crash, crashlytics

I got weird crash on Crashlytics, It's showing crash in the line as commented in code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row >= collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray.count {
        return UITableViewCell(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    var tableViewCell:CollectionsTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("collectionsCell") as? CollectionsTableViewCell
    if (tableViewCell == nil) {
        tableViewCell = CollectionsTableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "collectionsCell")
    }
    // Got crash in below line
    let collectionObject = collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray[indexPath.row]
    tableViewCell!.setCollection(collectionObject)

    return tableViewCell!
}
```

This is the stack trace that I got..

[image: Stack Traces]

But not getting why this even happened? I have already put check that

```
index.row >= collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray.count
```

so it should not be index out of range case. Can any one give me just one case in which this can happen?

**NOTE:** This happened with only one user till now but still why this even happened?

**Whole Table View Controller:**

```
import UIKit

class CollectionsViewController: CUIBaseViewController, CollectionArrayApiObjectDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {
var collectionsTableView : UITableView?
var collectionArrayApiObject : CollectionArrayApiObject = CollectionArrayApiObject()
var headerSearchButton : UIBarButtonItem?
var cityId: String?

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

convenience init(CityId: String? = nil) {
    self.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.cityId = CityId
    self.view.backgroundColor = Colors.white()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.setUpHeaderView()
    self.createTableView()
    self.getData()
    self.listenToNotifications()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: collectionsTableView!)
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}

func listenToNotifications() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CollectionsViewController.cityChanged), name: Constants.NOTIFIICATION_LOCATION_CHANGED_CITY, object: nil)
}

func cityChanged() {
    self.getData()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionsTableView?.frame = CGRectMake(0, Constants.NAV_BAR_HEIGHT, self.view.width, self.view.height - Constants.NAV_BAR_HEIGHT)
}

//MARK: view creation functions
func setUpHeaderView() {
    self.navigationItem.title = "Collections"

    let negativeSpacer = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    negativeSpacer.width = 0;

    headerSearchButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "n", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(CollectionsViewController.headerSearchButtonTapped))
    headerSearchButton?.width = 40
    headerSearchButton?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: Fonts.iconFont(18), NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Colors.gray()], forState: .Normal)

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [negativeSpacer, headerSearchButton!];
}

func createTableView() {
    collectionsTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectZero, style: .Plain)
    collectionsTableView?.separatorStyle = .None
    collectionsTableView?.backgroundColor = Colors.white()
    collectionsTableView?.dataSource = self
    collectionsTableView?.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(collectionsTableView!)
}

//MARK : tableview delegate methods
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CollectionsTableViewCell.getHeight()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row >= collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray.count {
        return UITableViewCell(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    var tableViewCell:CollectionsTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("collectionsCell") as? CollectionsTableViewCell
    if (tableViewCell == nil) {
        tableViewCell = CollectionsTableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "collectionsCell")
    }

    let collectionObject = collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray[indexPath.row]
    tableViewCell!.setCollection(collectionObject)

    return tableViewCell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    Commons.trackEvent(Commons.createGAcategory([Constants.COLLECTIONS_PAGE, "collection"]), action: "click", label: nil, value: 1)

    let exploreFeedForCollection = ExploreFeedViewController.init(collection: collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray[indexPath.row])

    //self.presentViewController(CUINavigationController.init(rootViewController: exploreFeedForCollection), animated: true, completion: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(exploreFeedForCollection, animated: true)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if (collectionsTableView != nil) {
        for cell in collectionsTableView!.visibleCells {
            if (cell.isKindOfClass(CollectionsTableViewCell.self)) {
                let cellOffset = cell.y - contentOffset;

                //image parallax
                let parallaxCut: CGFloat = 0.5
                let percent = (cellOffset + cell.height)/(collectionsTableView!.height + cell.height);
                let extraHeight = cell.height * (CollectionsTableViewCell.parallaxRatio-1.0) * parallaxCut;
                let collectionCell = cell as! CollectionsTableViewCell;                    
                collectionCell.bgImageView.y = -extraHeight*percent;
            }
        }
    }

}

//MARK : get cities data functions
func getData() {
    collectionArrayApiObject = CollectionArrayApiObject()
    collectionArrayApiObject.fetchCollections(Delegate: self, CityId: self.cityId)

    if collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray.count == 0 {
        self.showLoader("Hmm, things are getting interesting")
    }
}

func collectionsFetchedSuccessfully() {
    self.hideNothingHereViewAndLoader()
    self.collectionsTableView?.reloadData()
    self.scrollViewDidScroll(self.collectionsTableView!)
}

func collectionsFetchingFailed(errorType: ErrorType) {
    self.showNothingHereView(errorType, icon: nil, showTryAgain: true)
}

override func didTapReloadButton() {
    self.getData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let indexPath = collectionsTableView?.indexPathForRowAtPoint(location) else{
        return nil
    }

    // Lifting cell up on 3D touch before peeking
    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        let cellRect = collectionsTableView?.rectForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        let sourceRect = previewingContext.sourceView.convertRect(cellRect!, fromView: collectionsTableView)
        previewingContext.sourceRect = sourceRect
    }

    return ExploreFeedViewController.init(collection: collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
}

func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerToCommit, animated: true)
}

//MARK : header button functions
func headerSearchButtonTapped() {
    let searchVC = SearchViewController(CityId: cityId)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchVC, animated: true)
}

deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations:

**First**

Instead of using this `if` statement:

```
if indexPath.row >= collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray.count {
    return UITableViewCell(frame: CGRectZero)
}
```

You should use the `numberOfRowsInSection` to do that, like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray.count
}
```

**Second**

In your `cellForRowAtindexPath` you just have to dequeue the cell and than set it as you need, like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                //swift 3.0
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionsTableViewCell
                //swift 2.2
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionsTableViewCell

                let collectionObject = collectionArrayApiObject.collectionsArray[indexPath.row]
                cell.setCollection(collectionObject)
                return cell
            }
```

There isn't need to test if you use [dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) which according to the docs always returns a valid cell

Comment: First thing is already there in code, But long ago we were getting crashes saying list index out of range, not sure why But above if condition solved problem at that time.  Second.. to check if cell is not nil is required because tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("collectionsCell") can be nil if not created at all in first place.. Third.. In your solution you are saying only to remove safety checks but that will not solve current index out of range crash.. Please NOTE the stack trace.. CollectionsViewController.scrollViewDidScroll(UIScrollView) -> () tried to call tableView function.

Comment: Looks like your problem isn't is in the tableView. Probably in the api that provide your data. If is possible,try to you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:)  instead of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("collectionsCell‌​") it will guarantee returns a valid cell and you will not need the validation in cellForRowAtindexPath.

Comment: Nope.. It made crashing more frequent on simulator now, giving following stack trace..  Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:6573
0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011043fd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
But Initially all was working fine and I was not able to reproduce problem that I got in crashlytics.. But I am agree with your point that problem may be in api call and loading data.. but don't know why and how to solve that??

Comment: Could you add your entire tableview class in your question? Maybe it helps to clarify the problem.

Comment: Added.. Please see.. It's little long not sure It will help.. You may ask for specific functions.. Then It will easy for you also..

Comment: IMO, looks like the problem is in the synchronization between load data from CollectionArrayApiObject and the tableView. It seems to me that when CollectionArrayApiObject fires the collectionsFetchedSuccessfully the array is not ready. I'm saying that because your tableView code looks ok.

Comment: I have a sample code in github showing how I implement async load to tableview. Maybe it helps you: https://github.com/gazolla/JsonTableViewSwift

Comment: @KautsyaKanu did you find the solution? I am having similar crash.

Comment: @Pawriwes Now I am seeing these old questions when I was naive..  Sebastian was on point.. Most probably data in cells data started updating even when table reload was not complete.. Like If some one hit refresh and you remove all data from model to fetch new data.. but as tableView is still reloading because it's async.. that will crash app.. because It will expect data at nth index from numberOfItemsInSection method but it's disappearing when tableView came to cellForRowAtIndexPath..
Either try to update cellsData async on main or try other way just to ensure both are in sync..

Answer (score -1):

1- if you are using like this

let cell = tableChatHome.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableChatHomeCell1", for: indexPath) as! tableChatHomeCell1

2- change to like this work fine for me

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableChatHomeCell1") as! tableChatHomeCell1
```